# List of web development design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications

In wikipedia, there is an article about "web development" and another about "design patterns", but none about "web development design patterns".

The only one I know: PRG (Post/Redirect/Get).

Can anybody list them or give some references like books?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo has a comprehensive library that can be [accessed here](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/everything.html)

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Also Fielding can be your Friend. No Dev Pattern's but a more complete approach to PRG

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm